# How to compress email (without any attachment) using Gmail API send() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, gzip, gmail-api

I have tried manipulating headers, tried adding/replacing encoding to 'gzip' but adding new headers for to accept 'gzip' format or replacing current headers only increases the overall size of the email rather than reducing it.

My code:

```
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  # message.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
  # message.add_header('User-Agent', 'gzip')
  message.add_header('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')
  # message.replace_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'gzip')
  to_be_sent = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}
  return to_be_sent

def send_message(service, user_id, message):
  """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
    # print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
    return message
  except Exception as error:
    print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
```

To read the message:

```
# Call the Gmail API - read
message = service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=MESSAGE_ID, format="full").execute()
```

The [Gmail API performance tip](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance) states that:
An easy and convenient way to reduce the bandwidth needed for each request is to enable gzip compression.In order to receive a gzip-encoded response you must do two things: Set an Accept-Encoding header, and modify your user agent to contain the string gzip.

Accept-Encoding: gzip

User-Agent: my program (gzip)

Still not working for me. Only keeps the size either constant or increases it.

Comment: Cannot answer, but the gmail quote mentions a gzipped **response**, not the request...

Comment: Confirming the comment above, response is compressed, not the request. @VPfB, could you post the comment as answer so other people could vote on that? Thanks.

Comment: @OctaviaSima I'm glad If my comment was helpful, but I don't think I really answered the question "How to compress ...".

Comment: Post was specific and mentioned via send method, I think **it won't be possible** , followed by the reason is sufficient as an answer. @VPfB, that might not directly answer the question but is helpful on confirming the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be possible with the method you are asking for. As @VPfB mentioned, the documentation says response.

Although I thought of alternative and it is to compress the content/body if your sole purpose is to diminish the mail size. You can also decompress the content afterwards if needed be.

I did the test earlier. See the following results below:

#### Test conditions:

- Tested in Google Apps Script using Gmail API (python is unavailable in my device)
- Long string content test length: 8802
- Short string content test length: 452
- Test cases are generated through [here](https://randomwordgenerator.com/paragraph.php)
- Compression used is [LZ string compression](https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html)

#### Output (sizeEstimate):

- Long uncompressed: 18928
- Long compression: 18421
- Short uncompressed: 1627
- Short compression: 2081

#### Conclusion:

- If you are planning to use this on fairly short content emails, don't bother, it will not save you any storage and will only enlarge the size.
- If you are using it on long content emails, it saves a very little storage but it's up to you to decide if that is worth saving that much but having the need to decompress it every time you want to read the email.
- Reference includes both compress and decompress functions.
- See [Python implemenation by eduardtomasek](https://github.com/eduardtomasek/lz-string-python) if you want to test it on your end.